# Inconsistency between SQL SDK and Stored Procedure when handling long integer types

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Our team is using Cosmos DB as our backend graph storage. Basically we are using JAVA Gremlin SDK to do queries on vertices/edges, and using SQL SDK to create/update vertices, due to the size and step limit of Gremlin API.

I met this issue when trying to update a vertex that contains an attribute that has type Long.
In our code we use `CosmosDbElement` and another flag as input parameter, call `sqlClient.executeStoredProcedure(“sp_name”, pk, new Object[] { document, flag });`
The stored proc I use simply does some validation then calls `collection.replaceDocument()` to replace the document.

When I set different value on this attribute I got different behaviors:

1. Attribute value within [-2^53 + 1, 2 ^53 - 1] (MIN_SAFE_INTEGER to MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in JavaScript)

   - Replace with SQL SDK then get by ID: works well
   - Replace with SP then get by ID: works well
2. Attribute value outside above range and within the range of Int64

   - Replace with SQL SDK then get by ID: works well
   - Replace with SP then get by ID: Last 3 digits are rounded. E.g.

922337203685477**5107** -> 922337203685477**5000**;

922337203685477**5807** -> 922337203685477**6000**.

We can get the same rounded value using SQL SDK.

For most cases `g.V([id])` gets the same rounded value.
But if the rounded value is outside of the range of `Int64`, such as 922337203685477**5807** -> 922337203685477**6000**, `g.V([id])` throws exception: `Cannot create ValueField on non-primitive type BigInteger`.

3. Attribute outside of the range of Int64

   - Replace with SQL SDK then get by ID: works well
   - Replace with SP then get by ID: works well

Am I using SP in a right way?

Is it by design a limit or an issue?

How to avoid such precision lost and be able to query the vertex?

Let me know if you need more information, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Stored Procedures are written in JavaScript.
>
> As you know, JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754, and it can only safely hold numbers between `-(2^53 - 1)` and `2^53-1` (i.e., `9007199254740991`).
>
> So if you use a sproc to replace the value outside of the safe `MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` to `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in JavaScript, it will get rounded. This is a by-design limitation.

The recommended workarounds are:

> 1. If you are ok with the precision-loss, then converting the `Int64` values into doubles is recommended so that your application handles the conversion/rounding.
> 2. If you need to maintain the precision then use strings, with the downside being that arithmetic ops cannot be applied server-side.